# Cannot resolve classes from maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

Using Eclipse,

[image]

I have tried:

- Right click > Maven > Update project
- *mvn clean install* from cmdline

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message you get when you build with Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Deleted my .m2 folder and did `mvn clean install`